# StackApps question prompt needs to be more specific

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, asking-questions, stackapps

The [question prompt on StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/ask) could be more specific.

Now it says:

> what's your API, app, or library question? be specific.

If it took the advice in its own last "sentence" and instead said:

> what's your *Stack Exchange* API, app, or library question? be specific.

there would be exactly one fewer stray off-topic question there per month - and that makes it *totally worth making the change.*

Comment: Exactly one? Never two or zero?

Comment: @waiwai933: Very rarely four. Never two or zero.